# How to import contacts from AOL using asp.net? (api/dll/library)

Tags: asp.net, api, contacts, aol

How to import contacts from AOL using asp.net?

when I explore the buddylist api then I get following message.

```
"Closing of Userplane Business on August 1, 2013"
```

In the site http://dev.aol.com/apis/ you can find 'buddylist api' in APIs tab.
but its saying 'Closing of Userplane Business on August 1, 2013'

Any comments/suggestion or some dll/library or material?

Answer (score 0):

Now the AOL contacts API is based on [OAuth2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth2) (an open standard for authorization).

A nice article about OAuth2 workflow is: http://aaronparecki.com/articles/2012/07/29/1/oauth2-simplified

The AOL OAuth2 documentation is located at http://identity.aol.com/documentation/start/oauth2/

Additionally you can use ready-to-use solutions. I work at http://www.cloudsponge.com, and we provide HTML widget and service APIs to import contacts from Gmail, WindowsLive, AOL, Yahoo, etc, in several languages/platforms, like Java, PHP, Ruby, and .Net.